# Xamarin-FreshMVVM Init not working in async way

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, freshmvvm

It's a Xamarin application and I am trying to call an async method inside the **Init** implemented in **FreshMVVM**, but doesn't seems to work.

When I load the page the ListView is empty, although bindings are correct. In fact, if I remove the await calls putting some int constants, ListView is shown correctly.

```cs
public class MainPageModel : BasePageModel
{
    private IService _service;
    public List<ModeMenuItem> List { get; set; }

    public MainPageModel(IService Service)
    {
        _service = Service;
    }

    public override async void Init(object initData)
    {
        base.Init(initData);

        List = new List<ModeMenuItem>()
        {
            new ModeMenuItem()
            {
                Name ="Test 1",
                Image ="\uE7EE",
                ViewModelType =null,
                TotalRequests = await _service.Count()
            },
            new ModeMenuItem()
            {
                Name ="Test 2",
                Image ="\uE913",
                ViewModelType =null,
                TotalRequests =await _service.Count()
            },
            new ModeMenuItem()
            {
                Name ="Test 3",
                Image ="\uE8CF",
                ViewModelType =null
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are delaying population and initialization of your data you provide to the `ListView` you need to either:

1. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your ViewModel and fire it when you create your `List` property.
2. Make your `List` an `ObservableCollection` and have it instantiated in the constructor of the ViewModel, then just populate it at a later point of time.

You can also mix the two.

So option 1. would be to just raise the PropertyChanged event:

```
private List<ModeMenuItem> _list;
public List<ModeMenuItem> List 
{ 
    get => _list; 
    set
    {
        _list = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Option 2. would be:

```
public ObservableCollection<ModeMenuItem> List { get; } 
    = new ObservableCollection<ModeMenuItem>();
```

and then popluate it without newing up a new collection:

```
List.Add();
```

Comment: Great, I used option 2 with success!